# Spark sql join is giving out of memory exception

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with about 500k rows and 20 columns.
The data is broken down into levels, there are 10 levels in total (see image below that displays 5 levels) and the lower is the level the more data it contains (its actually the same data for all levels but for lower levels the data is more detailed), my goal is to fix some of the values in lower levels (from up to down), in order to do this i iteratively split the main dataset and collect one(parent) level and its direct child:

```
1&2
2&3
3&4
4&5....
```

I then join the parent and child dataset based on some common columns and perform the fix of the values:

```
 for (Triple<String, String, Seq<String>> aggregationTriple : getAggregationLevels())
      {
        String parentLevel = aggregationTriple.getLeft();
        String childLevel = aggregationTriple.getMiddle();
        Seq<String> aggregationCols = aggregationTriple.getRight();
        Dataset<Row> parents = finalDataset.where(col(agg).equalTo(lit(parentLevel)));
        Dataset<Row> children = data.where(col(agg).equalTo(lit(childLevel)));
        Dataset<Row> joined = parents.join(children, aggregationCols, "inner");
        //Add new calculated metrics
        for(int i=0; i < METRICS.length; i++)
        {
          String metric = METRICS[i];
          String newMetricName = NEW_METRICS[i];
          //We work only on metrics here
          joined = joined
              .withColumn(PERFORM VALUE FIX HERE);
        }
        finalDataset = finalDataset.union(joined.select(ArrayUtils.addAll(COLUMNS_KEYS, NEW_COLUMNS_METRICS)));
      }
    return finalDataset;
  }
```

The issue is that when this goes down to the lowest level (the ones with more data), i get an out of memory problem in production:
`Total size of serialized results of 16 tasks (1048.5 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)`
So i have given it more memory (2GB) but apparently is never enough, the more memory i set (3GB or 4GB) the more it consumes.
Searching on web i found out that this means that one of the workers is sending back to driver a chunk of data that is too big, but if the final file (500k rows) is 40MB how can a single worker, which is supposed to work on a little partition of that data, send such a big chunk of data?
My loop does not seem to create oversize files like in a boggy infinite loop.

Additional tests results, locally this time:
What i notice when i run it locally, is that spark internally produces an enormous amount of tasks: (26004)
[image]
For a relatively small parquet file (6MB)
Also, in the DAG visualization i see an enormous tree in which the leaves more or less all have the same representation:
[image]

I cant figure out why so many stages are created for such relatively small file.
pls any suggestion is very welcome
[image: here a little example]

Comment: please add the whole error

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue might be with Serialization
did you provide any serializer to SparkConf ??

If not provide the conf `--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer` in spark-submit.

If this works else, play with spark.kryoserializer.buffer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#compression-and-serialization